# Mocking and testing a function in Jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have the following function in a `helper.ts` file

```
export public myFunction = () => {
    const arr = [];
    for (let index = 0; index < 5; index++) {
        arr.push(i);
    }

    return arr;
}
```

How do I go about testing this in my Jest test?

Comment: You will need to provide more context.  Is this part of a class?  `private` is a [future reserved word](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-future-reserved-words) in JavaScript, is this TypeScript?

Comment: Ive changed the original post. Its not in a class. Its just a public function that sits inside a ts file.

Comment: what do you want to mock? it looks like you just want to test that you return an array of size five when you call this function

Answer (score 0):

Given a file `helper.ts`:

```
export const myFunction = () => {
  const arr = [];
  for (let index = 0; index < 5; index++) {
      arr.push(index);
  }
  return arr;
}
```

a test `helper.test.ts` can be created as follows:

```
import { myFunction } from './helper';

describe('myFunction', () => {

  it('should return an array with the numbers 0-4', () => {
    expect(myFunction()).toEqual([0,1,2,3,4]);
  });

});
```

Comment: @ZeroDarkThirty friendly reminder to upvote and mark as accepted if an answer gives you the info you need